# While getting consent, I'm prompted to login to my developer account (but can I skip this?)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have been working on connecting to the DocuSign API via a Blazor web app. For the most part, I have things working, except for the consent piece.

For context, my current build is mostly referencing https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client as the source, and I've modified what I needed from there. I've included code examples below. Additionally, I would like to say that I have tried just about every c# authorization flow DocuSign has documented, and in every case, it's also the consent piece where I run into issues.

Now, onto the specific issue: when I try to authorize consent (see code immediately below) with the returned Uri, I am prompted to login to DocuSign with my developer account. This is baffling to me, as I can't find any mention in their documentation that this is supposed to happen. From what I can tell, the user should be prompted to "Accept" or "Decline" the consent, but that is all. I can only assume I'm mistaken in my understanding of what's supposed to happen.

```
        public string GetAuthorizationURLforConsent()
        {
            // we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
            ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;

            // Give consent to your app
            // Adding signature as out scope.
            List<string> scopes = new List<string>
            {
                OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE,
                OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION
            };

            Uri oauthLoginUrl = apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(INTEGRATOR_KEY, scopes, REDIRECT_URI, OAuth.TOKEN, STATE);

            // create a new UriBuilder, which copies all fragments of the source URI
            UriBuilder newUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(oauthLoginUrl);

            // set the new host
            newUriBuilder.Host = "account-d.docusign.com";

            // get a Uri instance from the UriBuilder
            Uri newUri = newUriBuilder.Uri;

            //return oauthLoginUrl.AbsoluteUri;
            return newUri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

Here's the thing: If I just skip the consent piece, and keep things moving in my code with the JWTAuthLogin method, I can continue on and end with a successful result (later in the code, the user gets successfully taken to sign the PDF on the DocuSign site).

```
        public string JWTAuthLogin()
        {
            // we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
            ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;

            // ONE TIME STEP for granting consent
            // Update and Run the below Uri with your INTEGRATOR_KEY and REDIRECT_URI
            // Example authorization URI -> https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
            // response_type =code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=$INTEGRATOR_KEY&redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI"

            // OR Run the below method to get your app specific Uri generated for you...
            //string oauthLoginUrl = GetAuthorizationURLforConsent();
            // Once you give consent (one-time only) then you can continue with futher requests...

            string oAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com"; // for demo the base path would have "-d"

            OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(INTEGRATOR_KEY, USER_ID, oAuthBasePath, PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES, 1);

            OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token);

            string accountId = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in userInfo.Accounts)
            {
                if (item.IsDefault == "true")
                {
                    accountId = item.AccountId;
                    apiClient = new ApiClient(item.BaseUri + "/restapi");
                    break;
                }
            }

            return accountId;
        }
```

I suppose my question is: Am I understanding the flow correctly? Why do I have to sign in when attempting to get consent? Is that expected behavior? If it is expected behavior, can I skip that (without pissing off DocuSign lawyers)? It would appear that I can skip that step in practice, but they mention how important this step is quite often, and I would like to follow the correct procedures.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consent for only required once per app/integration.**

Let's answer your questions:

- Am I understanding the flow correctly? Yup, you do.
- Why do I have to sign in when attempting to get consent? Well, how would DocuSign know who is consenting if they didn't sign-in? the consent is tied to your individual user account and every user has to consent individually.
- Is that expected behavior? yup, it is.
- If it is expected behavior, can I skip that (without pissing off DocuSign lawyers)? not sure about the lawyers part, but you cannot skip it. It is only required once. Once a user gives consent to an app, and unless they explicitly revoke it later, they do not need to do this again, ever.

To summarize:

**Consent for only required once per app/integration.**

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. What you've said makes sense. I think what's confusing me are two things. First, if I only have to consent once, why does it make me consent each time I delete cache/cookies in my browser? Wouldn't DocuSign log the fact that I consented in their database or something and not store it locally on my machine? I suppose if I am running this code on a production server, I might not need to delete browser cache/cookies. The second thing is that it is in fact letting me skip the first step. If the consent piece is required, how am I able to skip it?

Comment: You are confused. You are being asked to log in again if you delete cookies, not to consent again. In fact, that's exactly the second part of your confusion - you're not being asked to consent again once you log in.

Comment: Since you're using JWT, the whole URL you're using is not needed anymore once consent was given. There's no need to login or ask for consent or anything. You can just request an accessToken to make API calls.

Comment: If you were using Auth Code Grant, then yes, you would need to login each time, but not consent. that is, like I said already, only required once per user, and is stored on the DocuSign servers associated with an individual user in an account.
Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thank you so much for clearing that up. I could tell I was confused, so I really appreciate you taking the time to followup with that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended alternative to having each user who will be impersonated by your application needing to grant individual consent, is to use `Administrative Consent`.

To use Administrative Consent:

1. Your account needs to have the "Access Management with SSO" feature. (But you don't need to install SSO.)
2. Your users who will be impersonated must have email addresses within an email domain that has been **claimed** via the DocuSign Administration tool.

Once the above is done, you, as an administrator can grant consent on behalf of your users. Remember to grant consent to both the `signature` and `impersonation` scopes.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I appreciate you taking the time to comment. I think my misunderstanding was that the consent piece only needed to happen once. For some reason, I thought that  the login prompt (when cookies were deleted) was part of the consent. I didn't realize that the one-time consent was separate from the login (when cookies were deleted). Thank you again for your help.